# Constraint between columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have got a table with two columns. How to set a constraint which would allow only lines where exactly one of the columns is null?

I certainly will do some prechecks in application layer but I would like to set this constraint also directly in database layer.

Thanks!

Comment: "*How to set a constraint which would **allow only lines** where exactly one of the columns is null?*". What do you mean, "*allow only lines*"?

Comment: Well, I found this: http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/08/mysql-check-constraint/

However, I do not know if this solves my problem.

Comment: _allow only lines_ means that Mysql throws an error on insert or update if the constraint is not fulfilled.

Comment: You need check constraints but MySQL does not support them so you need hacky workarounds like the link you found explains.

Answer (score 2):

try mysql operators [AND OR operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html)

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  `table1` 
    WHERE (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (col2 IS NULL AND col1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem.

Comment: @user1608790 Actually it does. You'll need this `WHERE` clause in an `BEFORE INSERT` and an `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger and that's it. Don't expect, that you always get the exact solution here at stackoverflow. The best way of helping is to give hints, so that the question asker can learn himself. +1 for being a "useful answer".

Comment: Sorry but I really did not recognized this should be used in some context. There is no sign of it.